# installing node sass gives an error message

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, sass

I'm using Visual studio code and I need to have sass installed on my machine. 
I tried to execute the following PowerShell command:
npm install node-sass and npm install -g node-sass, but both are not working.

when I built in visual studio code I get the following error message:

```
 node-sass : The term 'node-sass' is not recognized as the name of a
 cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
 of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
 correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
 + node-sass nbt.scss nbt.css
 + ~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node-sass:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

output of the powershell command is:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install -g node-sass
C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass -> C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass

> node-sass@4.13.1 install C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Cached binary found at C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\node-sass\4.13.1\win32-x64-64_binding.node

> node-sass@4.13.1 postinstall C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Binary found at C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-64\binding.node
Testing binary
Binary is fine
+ node-sass@4.13.1
updated 1 package in 6.765s
```

Can some of you guys help me out please? Thanks

Comment: `I tried to execute the following phowershell command ... but both are not working` - what does the error say specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by `when I built in visual studio code`? How are you using `node-sass`? Your installation - as your question asks - seems fine (via `npm i -g node-sass`)

Comment: im using nodesass as a compiler voor scss

Answer (score 0):

The fix is: just remove nodejs from your machine and install it again....